# Animate row of tableView to show actions (swipe left)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Have you seen on the iOS Facebook application, when sometimes you go check your notifications, the row of the tableView bounce in order to show that you can access actions? (Swipe left)

I would like to do the same, I succeeded to bounce the row left then right, but the actions behind the row don't show up. 
I guess this is because nobody calls the method `editActionsForRowAt`.

My current code to bounce is:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
let contentView = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.contentView
let original = contentView?.frame
var bounceOffset = original
bounceOffset?.origin.x -= 100

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
    contentView?.frame = bounceOffset!}) { _ in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.75, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        contentView?.frame = original!
    }, completion: nil)}
```

Do you have an idea of how I can do the same as Facebook?
A way to set `[UITableViewRowAction]`?